# ethers.js/node.js "unknown modifier: virtual" and "unknown modifier: override" when calling new ethers.Contract in class constructor

Tags: node.js, ethers.js

When instantiating a new ethers.Contract in class constructor, I get this for each declaration:

```
unknown modifier: virtual
unknown modifier: override
```

Im not sure what this means, I've tried to research how to get rid of this but with no luck.
I'm very new to javascript and node.js. It is not interrupting the program in any way it seems as the .exe runs fine with no errors besides this message every time new ethers.Contract is called in class constructor. I just want to know why this message is appearing.

The code where it happens and messages:

```
class pair{
    constructor(token0, token1, address){
        this._token0 = web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(token0);
        this._token1 = web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(token1);
        this._address = web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(address);
        this._pair_contract = new ethers.Contract(
            this._address,
            pair_abi_template,
            account
        );
        this._token0contract = new ethers.Contract(
            this._token0,
            abi_template,
            account
        );
        this._token1contract = new ethers.Contract(
            this._token1,
            abi_template,
            account
        );
    }
```

A new class instance is pushed into an array which is called via a subscription event like so:

```
let pair_array = [];
async function init(){
    let query = new Moralis.Query('PairCreatedEvents');
    let subscription = await query.subscribe();
    subscription.on('create', pair_created);// Call Pair Created Function
}
pair_created = async(p_event) => {
    pair_array.push(new pair(p_event.get('token0'), p_event.get('token1'), p_event.get('pair'))); 
}
```

The message:

```
unknown modifier: virtual
unknown modifier: override
unknown modifier: virtual
unknown modifier: override
unknown modifier: virtual
unknown modifier: override
unknown modifier: virtual
unknown modifier: override
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its because of the ABI, had the same problem.

for example change:

```
const IERC20 = [
  "function decimals() public view override returns (uint8)",
];
```

to this:

```
const IERC20 = [
  "function decimals() public view returns (uint8)",
];
```

if you remove the override or virtual from the function definition, it will not show the warning anymore. Removing the override/virtual from the ABI wont affect your code.